# How to set link for list item?

Tags: 2010, list

I have created a list in SharePoint 2010 and I would like to set the link for items that appear in a particular column in that list. For example, I have the following list:

```
| Status     | Code | Name   |
------------------------------
| Allowed    |  1   | Thing1 |
| Restricted |  2   | Thing2 |
| Allowed    |  3   | Thing3 |
```

I would like each item in the Name column to link to a page that displays details about that particular item (in a nicely formatted layout). Right now if you click on name, it will display the details about the item in SharePoint's standard item-info dialog box - which I don't want.

I am new at SharePoint so I don't know how can I accomplish this. Is it even possible? And if it is, how would you implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Calculated column of Hyperlink type.

Reference URL :https://devdotnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/sharepoint-caculated-column-and-hyperlink-no-workflow-or-script-needed/

Pass Item Title or other Unique field of item to the page and fetch the details of the item on nicely formatted page.

Also you can customize the default form i.e. standard item-info dialog box using SharePoint Designer

Comment: But you can not use ID in a Calculated Column

Comment: Agreed. ID cannot be fetched directly but using script the ID can be concatenated to URL.
Or instead of using ID in calculated column other column details can also be used to fetch item on other page

Comment: Then post a code example how to fetch that ID, because the way your answer is formatted people will now think they can include [ID] in a Formula.